# Laptop with integrated and discrete card

Tags: hardware, graphics, laptop, hardware-compatibility

I want to buy Lenovo yoga 710. I am concerned about general compatibility of this laptop with Linux especially graphics card. It has two graphics card. One is integrated with Intel processor other is discrete Nvidia 940MX. On windows Nvidia switches off when it is not needed and activates when it is needed (optimus technology). Does it work same on Linux?

Comment: It depends on what distribution of linux for more info se the link http://www.thelinuxrain.com/articles/the-state-of-nvidia-optimus-on-linux I do not think you want move on linux especially if you are beginner in linux

Comment: I use linux for like 12 years now so I am not a begginer. Up to this point I've never had a laptop and I know that NVidia/ATI support for Linux is a joke. That is why I ask.

Comment: I doubt you will get a definitive answer here.  But if you go ahead with your purchase and find out, you might consider self-answering this question.  :)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 1):

I can tell you about my experiences so far. I got a Acer Aspire V5 Nitro with an i5 and nvidia 940m. I'm using Fedora 25 with the default nouveau driver. Maybe that nouveau lacks in performance, but it handles dynamic switches very well. Mostly i have it off power saving, even hdmi is working.

Comment: Does it switch automatically or do you have to make it switch somehow?

Comment: @Trismegistos It will stay powered down until you invoke it with the necessary command or link it with an application. Most of the time i dont use the nvidia one due to power saving reason.

Comment: Can you tell me what the command is?

Comment: Yeah I'd be interested in that too..